# Drawing a picture and save it without displaying it

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, node-webkit

hat I want to do is to draw a picture with a png over another one, I've already successfully done it by canvas, and then I can save it as a new png file.

```
            var drawImage = function(canvas, base, overlay){
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                var baseImage = new Image();
                var overlayImage = new Image();
                var readyFlag = 0;
                var drawFunc = function () {
                    context.drawImage(baseImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    context.drawImage(overlayImage, 0, 0);
                }
                baseImage.onload = function () {
                    readyFlag += 1;
                    if (readyFlag < 2) {
                        return;
                    }
                    drawFunc();
                }
                overlayImage.onload = function () {
                    readyFlag += 1;
                    if (readyFlag < 2) {
                        return;
                    }
                    drawFunc();
                }
                baseImage.src = base;
                overlayImage.src = overlay;
            }
```

I want to save the picture to a path, but I don't want to display it, how I can achieve this or there is any plugin can did this.

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved it by myself, I found if I draw the canvas one by one very quickly and save you didn't notice the canvas changed, so the image seemed saved without displaying but actually displayed in a very short period of time.